# Django tests slows after MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, django, macos-sierra

I'm working on a Django project using Python 3 and Django 1.10 on Mac.

Before update I was running 40 tests in 0.441s.

Now after MacOS Sierra: Ran 40 tests in 5.487s

I did some investigations and found this line to be the problem:

```
response = self.client.post(r('subscriptions:new'), data)
```

If I pass a empty dict instead of data, the tests run faster. Anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Is it just this that's running slow?

Comment: Can you share the relevant view code?

Comment: How recently did you install Sierra? It may take a while for some CPU-intensive background tasks to finish.

Comment: @James111 That i notice yes. Several friends of mine are having the same problem.

Comment: @elethan My code on github: [link](https://github.com/lucasgondim/eventex-lucasgondim)

Comment: @James I installed it from Mac App Store. But I turned off the notebook several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that to resolve local DNS was taking forever to resolve.

If anyone has the same problem run this commands:

```
sudo scutil --get LocalHostName
sudo scutil --get HostName
```

If the result is not the same, use this commands to put them equal:

```
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName My-MacBook
sudo scutil --set HostName My-MacBook
```

Where `My-Macbook` is your local machine hostname.
Problem solved to me.